# Dialogflow : display "processing" message on intents triggered by followup events

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I've been working on a Dialogflow chatbot that calls a webhook which can often take more than the 5s delay to process and answer the user's request. So, following [this post](https://discuss.api.ai/t/fulfilment-using-webhook-takes-time-to-get-the-data/3726/31), my webhook sends a response containing a followup event if the processing is too long, and will be able to answer the following request sent by the intent triggered by the event.

Now, while this approach is working great, I have two questions :

1. Is there any way to send a message ("Please wait, I'm processing your request") to the user on every followup event ?
2. Since I'm using the Dialogflow-Messenger integration, is there any way to display the three dots "typing" animation while the webhook is processing the request ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing a chatbot, you should keep in mind that you are trying to duplicate how 2 humans interact. You are developing a conversation and in the conversation, we should not keep other person waiting. All your requests should be completed within 4-5 seconds (to avoid timeout by the platform) to have a better UX.

So there is no way to show either Please Wait or animated 3 dots!

Write a good backend code to fetch response faster or tweak and cache your response. Dialogflow is currently designed for 1-1 conversation and cannot provide multiple delayed responses. If you need it that way, you will require to develop your own NLP engine.

Comment: Many use cases of this bot consist of multiple requests on different google drive documents that I can't cache, so most of the requests take between 5 and 7 seconds to process. But you're right, maybe dialogflow isn't the best chatbot engine to use in my case.

Comment: Even the other platforms will not support what you are asking. You need to find better use case or change your backend.

Comment: Not a super helpful answer. I have a SQL query that takes more than 5 seconds to execute because of the way the database is, and I can't change anything about the structure of the database.

Comment: I suppose the best way to deal with this ATM is to warn the user that some of their requests may take a while to process.

Comment: Giving a waiting message is a valid scenario. for example if we do a reservation system, until we do the confirmation in backend (fulfilment) bot might say "please give me 1 second to confirm your resevation" and then say "It is confirmed" even if we are responding within 5 secs right?

Comment: It is valid but not supported as of now. For every request to the bot you will get one response that too within 5 sec.